# C++ shortcut for writing function with template class as a parameter

Tags: c++, templates, default-value

Is there a shortcut for writing a function that takes a templated class as a parameter when most of the specific template parameters don't matter?

Given

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename C, typename D, typename E> 
class Foo
```

I want to write

```
template<typename A>
int metric(Foo<A> x, Foo<A> y)
```

in this case, template parameters B through E are irrelevant.  Is there a way to avoid writing

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename C, typename D, typename E>
int metric(Foo<A, B, C, D, E> x, Foo<A, B, C, D, E> y)
```

Parameters B through E have defaults, but I want metric to work for all instantiations, not just those that use the default values of B through E.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<class A, class...Ts,class...Us>
int metric(Foo<A, Ts...> x, Foo<A, Us...> y)
```

This permits the two `Foo` types to be different.  If you want the same only:

```
template<class A, class...Ts>
int metric(Foo<A, Ts...> x, Foo<A, Ts...> y)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this if one of the template parameters is value instead of a typename (e.g., `template<typename A, typename B, typename C, bool D, typename E>`)?

Comment: @zack not really.  If you want to have good metaprogramming support, avoid non-type template parameters

Answer (score 0):

Try variadic template:

```
template<typename A, typename ... others>
int metric(Foo<A, others...> x, Foo<A, others...> y)
```

For this declaration it doesn't matter how many template parameters are there and what are their types. The only restriction is that both `x` and `y` must be instantiated with the same set of types. If this restriction is unwanted, see Yakk's answer. Also it allows you to write partial specializations, if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could declare metric as

```
template<typename T>
int metric(T x, T y)
```

and then template parameter deduction should work:

```
Foo< whatever parameters > f,g;
int x = metric(f,g);            // no need to specify parameters again
```